# How to root and flash a android Galaxy Ace s5830t?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, rom-flashing, root-access, samsung-galaxy-ace

i am trying to root my device which has android 2.3 in it. The reason is something has gone wrong and wifi and bluethooth are not functioning. every time i try connect,  it says error and automatically gets disabled. so i decided to, root the device and install a fresh ROM.  i am able to root it but when trying to install the ROM it doesnt allow me. it prioritizes TELSTRA.

Any help on this is highly appreciated from android geeks.

**EDIT1**

i was able to flash it and now there is a problem that phone is not starting up. its stucked in well come screen for more than half and hour now. but i saw in the screen instead of galaxy ace S5830T it shows S5830 which is a change. anyways to recover this kind of a situation ?

Answer (score 1):

According to this old [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=24543811&postcount=17) it's the same as the S5830. I'm not really sure though, you need to investigate this on your own if have doubt. Note also, that your S5830 is a legacy device and only really runs Android 2.3 well.

So you could either follow CyanogenMod's [installation instructions for the S5830](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_cooper) or search the S5830 section on XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?s=97a180c89815462ad70d71defd95e1bc&f=1725).

Note: If you want to replace the stock firmware, you don't have to root it in the first place; it's not needed to be able to flash it. You'll have root with the modded firmware, then.

Comment: i was able to flash it and now there is a problem that phone is not starting up. its stucked in well come screen for more than half and hour now. but i saw in the screen instead of galaxy ace S5830T it shows S5830 which is a change. anyways to recover this kind of a situation ?

Comment: What did you exactly do/install?

Comment: well i installed the CWM, then rooted the phone again, made a backup of the earlier system. then flashed the new ROM.

Comment: The Myth ROM final is what i just installed.

Comment: It's still dead? Did you do a factory reset (wipe) in CWM? Plus: You probably want the right google apps (http://goo.im/gapps).

Comment: Nope, it is working now. But still the wifi and bluetooth issue exists. when i try to turn on wifi, it says error and gets disabled. any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: From what i've read it's discontinued. Did you install the latrst version? You may try a different ROM ( eg. CM7.2 http://get.cm/?device=cooper) or check the thread over at XDA for pointers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1737805

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Micro SD card, download a different ROM to your phone. My phone wouldn't ring after I did a factory reset, changing the ROM worked for me. If you don't have a Miscro SD then connect your phone to the computer and open your files for the phone to see the direct path and move from your computer to your phone. If you don't have the new OS on your computer goto http://d-h.st/TxQ to download the Dark Unicorn ROM, you will need a zip extractor, either on your computer or your phone.